# Finding $\gcd(x^3, x^3+x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $f(x) = x^3$ and $g(x) = x^3+x+1$. I am trying to show that the $\gcd(f,g)= 1$ but am running into some trouble...

My attempt: (Division algorithm)

$x^3+x+1 = (1)(x^3)+(x+1)$

$x^3 = x^2(x+1)-x^2$

But I cannot go further than this, what is going wrong here?

Comment: You need the remainder to be smaller degree than the quotient, so you can divide by $x+1$ some more.  Instead, $x^3=(x^2-x+1)(x+1)-1$.

Comment: Your division algorithm for the second is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep going.  You found that

$$
x^3+x+1 = (1)(x^3) + (x+1)
$$

Now observe that

$$
x^3 = (x^2-x+1)(x+1) - (1)
$$

What can you conclude?

Comment: The GCD is then 1

Answer (score 0):

The gcd of $x^3+x+1$ and $x^3$ is the same as the gcd of $x^3$ and $(x^3+x+1)-x^3=x+1$.

Now $x+1$ is irreducible and doesn't divide $x^3$. End.

By the way, the remainder of the division of $f(x)=x^3$ by $x+1$ is $f(-1)=-1$ and, indeed, $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, but it's not needed.